# Qt : No such slot QObject::SlotName(QNetworkReply*)

Tags: c++, qt, rest, qt-signals

I am new to QT, and I am trying to connect to a REST service and get data. I am able to successfully connect to the local tomcat on my machine, but I am getting the slot not found error. Kindly let me know what I might be doing wrong, I don't have that much expertise in Qt, so please bear with me

Person.cpp :

```
#include "person.h"
 #include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include<QObject>
#include<QDebug>
#include<QNetworkReply>

Person::Person()
{

}

Person::~Person()
{

}
void Person::addPerson (){


    QString url_str = "http://localhost:8080/";

    Person *person = new Person;
    person->setAccountStatus (true);
    person->setFirstName ("Akshay");
    person->setId (0);
    person->setPassword ("helloWorld");
    person->setUsername ("akshay@gmail.com");

    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();

    QObject object;
    object.connect(manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),SLOT(slotRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl (url_str);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/json");
    QNetworkReply *reply = 0;
    manager->get(request);
```

}

```
void Person::slotRequestFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qDebug()<<"Task finished";
}
```

Person.h :

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
#include<QString>
#include<QObject>
#include<QNetworkReply>

class Person
{
private:
     qint32 id;
     QString username;
     QString password;
     QString firstName;
     bool accountStatus;

public:
    Person();
    ~Person();

    qint32 getId() const;
    void setId(const qint32 &value);

    QString getUsername() const;
    void setUsername(const QString &value);

    QString getPassword() const;
    void setPassword(const QString &value);

    QString getFirstName() const;
    void setFirstName(const QString &value);

    bool getAccountStatus() const;
    void setAccountStatus(bool value);
    void addPerson();

public slots:
  void slotRequestFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);


protected:

    QList<Person> listPersons();


};

#endif // PERSON_H

}
```

And I am calling this from main.cpp :

```
Person *person = new Person;
person->addPerson ();
```

Error log :

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QObject::connect: No such slot QObject::slotRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*) in ../CheckNet/person.cpp:81
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
```

Edit : Adding QObject :

```
class Person : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private :
// values, getters and setters
}
```

When i do the above, I get the following error :

```
/home/akshay/Qtprojects/CheckNet/person.cpp:57: error: undefined reference to `vtable for Person'
/home/akshay/Qtprojects/build-CheckNet-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/person.o:-1: In function `Person::~Person()':
```

Comment: The class `Person` should inherit `QObject` and you need to add `Q_OBJECT` macro in the class declaration.

Comment: @vahancho : Can you please check my post, before also I tried to add QObject and its macro the above way, but it fails with the error mentioned in the post.

Comment: Have you tried rerunning qmake and rebuilding the entire project after doing what vahancho told you ?

Comment: Is `Person.h` added to the `.pro` file? E.g. `HEADERS += Person.h`.

Comment: @Slyps : Yes, I presume he meant what I have pasted in edit.

Comment: @DanielRobertson : Yes., in HEADERS +=, there is person.h

Comment: Is there a reason why you defined Person::slotRequestFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
In the .h file?

Comment: @Marco : Shouldn't I define slots in .h file?

Comment: @Marco Im more puzzled about that extra `}` after `#endif` ^^

Comment: @WeareBorg You can **define** slots whereever c++ allows member function to be defined.

Comment: @Slyps : Is that the problem or the Q_OBJECT macro? Can you please suggest me a correction?

Comment: You mean what Macro said ? No its just fine to define your member function there. Or the `}` ? The most likely error would then be a compiler error, not linker error, so its probably just a side effect of you butchering parts of your code into your question. I'm still betting my money on rerunning qmake and rebuilding, heck even deleting your shadow build if nothing helps. Just make sure you have `Q_OBJECT` inside your class body,  your header added to `HEADERS` in your .pro file and inherit from `QObject`. If really none of this works, you have to provide an MCVE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Introduction

By using the non-static member-function [`QObject::connect`](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/4.8/qobject.html#connect-3) on a freshly created `QObject` (named `object` in your snippet), you are effectively saying that the provided `SLOT` is part of the object which you are currently invoking the member-function on.

```
QObject object;
object.connect(...);
    // ^- almost always wrong (deleteLater is the only slot in `QObject`)
```

With the logic above we can quite easily see the reason for the error you are describing; `QObject` doesn't have the relevant slot.

---

---

#### Solution

Either you can invoke the non-static [`QObject::connect`](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/4.8/qobject.html#connect), taking three arguments, on the object which really has the desired `SLOT` (in your case `Person`).

<sub>**Example**</sub>

```
// .- make sure `this` belongs to an object that inherits `QObject`
// v
   this->connect (
     manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), 
     SLOT(slotRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*))
   );
```

---

Another alternative would be to use the *static* member-function from `QObject`, where the 3rd argument denotes the object which has the `SLOT`:

<sup>**Example**</sup>

```
QObject::connect (
  manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
     this,   SLOT(slotRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*))
);
```

---

<sup>**Note**: In the above `this` denotes an object of type `Person`, the context required is inside a non-static member-function of `Person`, such as `addPerson` in your snippet.</sup>

<sup>**Note**: Remember that the objects passed as *sender* and *receiver* must inherit from `QObject`, which `Person` currently doesn't.</sup>

Comment: Awesome man, that did it. Can you please point me to some resources too about Qt, I come from Java, so its a bit different for me.

Comment: @WeareBorg The [Qt Reference Documentation](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/4.8/) is a great resource, other than that I recommend using google to find an appropriate learning resource.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp Kudos, I didn't even look at his connect attempt and thought he was not getting rid of the vtable error :D

Comment: You also mentioned object.connect(...); being wrong, what can I do for that??

Comment: @WeareBorg simply don't use that approach. `;-)`

Comment: Hey man, can you please have a  look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29234383/spring-mvc-qt-wont-accept-json-object-post-request  .Thanks a lot.